# Usage of the word "sufficient"

Tags: word-usage, usage

Is it correct to say: I know sufficient about the subject, or would it be correct to say I know enough about the subject? I heard people use the first version, but however, I am not a native speaker, to me is is sound somehow unnatural

Comment: "I know sufficient about the subject" sounds very awkward to these American ears. I'm not sure if it's grammatical or not, but if I had to choose, I'd say not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say this use of "sufficient" is *incorrect*.  It does also sound wrong to my American ears, but I have heard it used by some British English speakers.  I would say "I know *enough*".

If I wanted to use "sufficient" in this context, it would have to be related to some attribute:

> My **knowledge** of the language is **sufficient** (for me to get around comfortably in that country)
>
> I am **sufficiently fluent** in the language (that I can get around comfortably in that country).